# Using ffmpeg to combine small mp4 chunks?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to convert batches of png images into a single mp4 x264 video using ffmpeg. The conversion, for reasons I won't go into, converts groups of frames into short mp4 chunks and then I want to take those chunks and merge them into the final video at a specific fps (in this case 30fps).

My understanding of ffmpeg and the x264 options is too limited, and while I can produce the individual mp4 chunks from the source png frames without trouble, the final merge always ends up duplicating and/or dropping frames especially with very short chunks (< 4 frames).

The conversion from png to mp4 uses this command:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1001 -framerate 30 -f image2 -i 'intermediate.%d.png' -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -frames:v 4 -r 30 chunk.1.mp4 -y
```

which appears to work as expected, I get a playable mp4 chunk of, in this case, 4 frames of the sequence of png images at 30fps. The length of each chunk can be anywhere from 1 frame to around 100 frames.

When all the chunks are generated, I've been trying to use the concat demuxer to combine without re-encoding, placing all the source chunk paths in a file:

concat.txt:

```
file 'chunk.1.mp4'
file 'chunk.2.mp4'
file 'chunk.3.mp4'
...
```

and then running this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c:v copy merged.mp4 -y
```

but it says this during the concatenation:

[concat @ 0x315ff80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

and the resulting mp4 has dropped/duplicated frames. So I tried adding duration info to the concat.txt file:

```
file 'chunk.1.mp4'
duration 0.133333
file 'chunk.2.mp4'
duration 0.133333
file 'chunk.3.mp4'
duration 0.066666
```

in this case, two 4-frame/30fps chunks and one 2-frame/30fps chunk. Which gets rid of that estimation warning, but the result is still duplicating/dropping frames.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here...what do I need to do either in the production of the short mp4 segments, or in the combination stage, to get a single mp4 at the right framerate with no duplicated or dropped frames?

As suggested, here's the console output for the conversion from png->mp4 chunks:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -start_number 1001 -framerate 30 -f image2 -i 'intermediate.%d.png' -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -frames:v 4 -r 30 chunk.1.mp4 -y
ffmpeg version 2.5.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 26 2015 10:23:42 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/bundle.rhel6/ffmpeg2.5.4 --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-x11grab --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/extern/rhel6/include --extra-ldflags=-L/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/extern/rhel6/lib --enable-libx264 --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-swscale --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --disable-yasm
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'intermediate.%d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 1024x1024 (0x0), 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x273e9c0] w:1024 h:1024 pixfmt:rgba tb:1/30 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0x2737ea0] w:iw h:ih flags:'0x4' interl:0
[format @ 0x273ece0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[auto-inserted scaler 0 @ 0x2737ea0] w:1024 h:1024 fmt:rgba sar:0/1 -> w:1024 h:1024 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=36 lookahead_threads=6 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'chunk.1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1024x1024, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[mp4 @ 0x273baa0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     197kB time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=24228.7kbits/s    
video:196kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.439751%
Input file #0 (intermediate.%d.png):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 8 packets read (2341016 bytes); 5 frames decoded; 
  Total: 8 packets (2341016 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (chunk.3.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 4 frames encoded; 4 packets muxed (201023 bytes); 
  Total: 4 packets (201023 bytes) muxed
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] frame I:1     Avg QP: 0.47  size:116049
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] frame P:1     Avg QP: 2.29  size: 37932
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] frame B:2     Avg QP: 2.37  size: 23184
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] consecutive B-frames: 25.0%  0.0% 75.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] mb I  I16..4: 80.0%  4.5% 15.5%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.4%  P16..4:  8.1%  3.6%  3.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:83.9%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  4.8%  1.2%  1.6%  direct: 4.3%  skip:88.1%  L0:38.6% L1:39.3% BI:22.1%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] 8x8 transform intra:4.6% inter:14.8%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 20.7% 22.9% 22.8% inter: 8.7% 10.1% 10.0%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] i16 v,h,dc,p: 95%  1%  3%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 21% 22%  6%  6%  6%  7%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 17% 18%  7%  8%  7%  8%  6%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] i8c dc,h,v,p: 89%  4%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] ref B L1: 89.5% 10.5%
[libx264 @ 0x273c540] kb/s:12020.88
```

as I said, this appears to produce a valid mp4 at 30fps with no duplicated or dropped frames from the input images.

Here's the output of the combine phase:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -f concat -i concat.txt -c:v copy merged.mp4 -y
ffmpeg version 2.5.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 26 2015 10:23:42 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/bundle.rhel6/ffmpeg2.5.4 --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-x11grab --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/extern/rhel6/include --extra-ldflags=-L/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/extern/rhel6/lib --enable-libx264 --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-swscale --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --disable-yasm
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, concat, from 'concat.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x1024, 7791 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'merged.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1024x1024 (0x0), q=2-31, 7791 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=   20 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     748kB time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=10805.0kbits/s    
video:746kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.141687%
Input file #0 (concat.txt):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 20 packets read (764361 bytes); 
  Total: 20 packets (764361 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (merged.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 20 packets muxed (764361 bytes); 
  Total: 20 packets (764361 bytes) muxed
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include your console output.

That said, out of curiosity, can you try using the concatenate filter and combining this all into one command and see if that changes anything.  It would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1001 -r 30 -i 'intermediate_1.%d.png' -i 'intermediate_2.%d.png' -i 'intermediate_3%d.png' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map [v] -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart Output.mp4
```

Comment: Interesting...knowing extremely little about the concatenation filter, I tried this except I used it to concatenate the mp4 chunks into a final mp4, and using this method, it appears to create a good result with no duplicated or dropped frames:

`ffmpeg -i chunk.1.mp4 -i chunk.2.mp4 -i chunk.3.mp4 -i chunk.4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [3:0] concat=n=4:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -crf 1 filter.mp4 -y`

but I assume this is not simply copying the inputs to the outputs for the merge, but is re-encoding the whole thing?

Comment: You cannot stream copy when applying filters in FFmpeg.

However, in your original post, it appears that you wanted to re-encode the file to libx264 using `-c:v libx264`.

If instead you want to maintain the quality of the original media - and if file sizes are not a concern for you, try using an uncompressed codec.  You can specify an uncompressed codec with `-c:v rawvideo`  Keep in mind, if you go uncompressed, delete your `-crf 1` argument.

Comment: Not exactly: there are two steps. In the first step, conversion from png -> mp4, it's fine to encode, and I can manage the quality settings as needed. What I'm trying to avoid is any further quality degradation in the second step, going from mp4 -> mp4, when I join all the mp4 chunks together into one final mp4 video. That's where I was trying to find a concatenation that would work and produce a no-drop-frame and no-duplicate-frame, constant 30fps video combining all the source videos.

Comment: You can maintain the quality using `-c:v rawvideo`.  If you specify `-c:v libx264` you will re-encode the media.  Out of curiosity, is there a reason you don't want to do this all in one command like my original answer suggests?  Instead of producing intermediary MP4 "chuncks", you could just send your png sequence directly into the concatenate filter.  That way you encode the file one time and can keep the file sizes down.....  If for some reason you don't want to do this, you can always use the concatenate protocol to do the last step.  That way you could use `-c:v copy` and not reencode

Comment: I think I'm just repeating the initial post of the question here: unfortunately, the way the system I'm doing this for works, I have to merge mp4s made from png image sequences. The mp4 chunks are made ahead of time, and then merged later. The end result must still be one mp4, so going to raw video doesn't work. If I could have avoided the intermediate mp4 step, I definitely would have.

Comment: Unfortunately, the concatenate protocol doesn't work, since mp4 does not appear to be one of the types of files that ffmpeg can successfully concatenate that way (I think it only works with mpeg streams). I tried it, just to be sure and it only gave me the first chunk in the result. I also tried converting first to an intermediate format like mpegts which can be merged via the concatenate protocol, but that ended up with the same issue that using the concatenate demux did: dropped frames and duplicated frames, with the wrong fps.

Comment: Could you instead create an uncompressed MP4 from the PNG sequence?  That way when you use the concatenate filter to combine the MP4 files you could compress them to H264 at the last step.  It should theoretically give you the same end result you are looking for - a one time h264 compressed and concatenated file.

Comment: That sounds plausible...what's the incantation to produce an uncompressed mp4? I could probably produce temporary uncompressed mp4 chunks and then only compress the merged result using the filter_complex.

Comment: To produce an uncompressed mp4, replace your `-c:v libx264` with `-c:v rawvideo` in your original command.  Also remove `-crf 1` from the command as well.