# ffmpeg concatenate with dynamic chunks

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, live-streaming, wowza

The ffmpeg docs for concat lists the following way
`ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output`

The mylist.txt file contains file like
    file '/path/to/file1'
    file '/path/to/file2'
    file '/path/to/file3'

What I am looking is for a way to do this concat in a persistent way where the number of files can keep increasing, for example in livestreaming
I will be sending chunks of video (mp4 files) of 10 seconds each to my server and want to concat/stitch them together to output to a **RTMP** stream (for livestreaming)

If concat is not the proper way to do this, please suggest alternatives.

Really interested to know how people use the above concept (I hope its how it works) to send video chunks from mobile device for livestreaming

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg docs have an example that does exactly what you're asking: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

This is their example:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn_concat_init() {
    echo "fn_concat_init"
    concat_pls=`mktemp -u -p . concat.XXXXXXXXXX.txt`
    concat_pls="${concat_pls#./}"
    echo "concat_pls=${concat_pls:?}"
    mkfifo "${concat_pls:?}"
    echo
}

fn_concat_feed() {
    echo "fn_concat_feed ${1:?}"
    {
        >&2 echo "removing ${concat_pls:?}"
        rm "${concat_pls:?}"
        concat_pls=
        >&2 fn_concat_init
        echo 'ffconcat version 1.0'
        echo "file '${1:?}'"
        echo "file '${concat_pls:?}'"
    } >"${concat_pls:?}"
    echo
}

fn_concat_end() {
    echo "fn_concat_end"
    {
        >&2 echo "removing ${concat_pls:?}"
        rm "${concat_pls:?}"
        # not writing header.
    } >"${concat_pls:?}"
    echo
}

fn_concat_init

echo "launching ffmpeg ... all.mkv"
timeout 60s ffmpeg -y -re -loglevel warning -i "${concat_pls:?}" -pix_fmt yuv422p all.mkv &

ffplaypid=$!

echo "generating some test data..."
i=0; for c in red yellow green blue; do
    ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=720x576:r=12:d=4 -pix_fmt yuv422p -vf "drawbox=w=50:h=w:t=w:c=${c:?}" test$i.mkv
    fn_concat_feed test$i.mkv
    ((i++));
    echo
done
echo "done"

fn_concat_end

wait "${ffplaypid:?}"

echo "done encoding all.mkv"
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with a dynamic png image overlay to a live stream, I can't get my head around how this script is working...

Answer (score -1):

I try to concatenate several webm files with command below and it works (in my case)

```
ffmpeg -i chunk.1.webm -i chunk.2.webm -i chunk.3.webm -i chunk.4.webm -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [3:0] concat=n=4:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" filter.webm -y
```

[Using ffmpeg to combine small mp4 chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360651/using-ffmpeg-to-combine-small-mp4-chunks#comment48814050_30360803)